# Haskell loadMatrixf

Tags: opengl, haskell

Where is the OpenGL function for loadMatrixf and what is the type signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Matrix class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OpenGL/latest/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-CoordTrans.html#t%3aMatrix).  I think you are looking for either `newMatrix` or the `matrix` StateVar in those docs.

For example: let `mat` be a list of 16 floats representing the matrix.  Then you would use it something like this:

```
import qualified Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL as GL

drawThingWithMatrix :: [GL.GLfloat] -> IO ()
drawThingWithMatrix mat = GL.preservingMatrix $ do  -- instead of push/pop
    newmat <- GL.newMatrix GL.RowMajor mat          -- or ColumnMajor
    GL.currentMatrix GL.$= newmat
    -- draw your thing
```

That's *about* right I think. It has been a while.