# Haskell retrieve opengl matrix (glGetFloatv)

Tags: opengl, haskell, matrix

Ok, having covered setting the matrices by hand ( [Haskell loadMatrixf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108335/haskell-loadmatrixf) ) I would now like to retrieve them. How can I do this?

In C it would be like this:

```
float m[4*4];
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, m);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenGL bindings for haskell uses [StateVar](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/StateVar/1.0.0.0/doc/html/Data-StateVar.html) to access and manipulate the OpenGL state, so if you were able to set the current matrix with

```
currentMatrix $= ...
```

you should be able to read it with

```
get currentMatrix
```

Answer (score 3):

I presume you would use [withNewMatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OpenGL/latest/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-CoordTrans.html#t%3aMatrix) and [glGetFloatv](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OpenGLRaw/1.1.0.1/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-Raw-Core31.html), but getting matrices *out* of OpenGL is far less common then getting them *in* and raises some cause for concern.

Comment: I wanted to check that my equivalent of GLU.perspective was working correctly